# set up Audio-Technica AT-LP140XP

Tags: preamp, vinyl

I want to buy an "[Audio-Technica AT-LP140XP](https://www.thomann.de/fr/audio_technica_at_lp140xp_silver.htm)". I saw that this turntable did not have a "preamp" so I imagine that you have to buy one too.

I have only theoretical knowledge in this area and I would like to know if what I plan bought seems correct to you.

My list :

1. [Audio-Technica AT-LP140XP](https://www.thomann.de/fr/audio_technica_at_lp140xp_silver.htm)
2. [Presonus Eris E3.5](https://www.thomann.de/fr/presonus_eris_e3.5.htm)
3. [ART DJ Pre II](https://www.thomann.de/fr/art_dj_pre_ii_b_stock_2.htm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the three items will work together.

You are correct, a turntable needs a pre-amp or a "phono stage".

Before CD's changed the market place all (*most*) stereos, Pre-amps or integrated amps had a phono stage built into them so all you had to do was plug your turntable into the Phono RCA inputs on the back of the unit.

Now only higher end components have Phono inputs with a phono stage. There are hundreds of Phono stages on the market today, you can spend lots of money on them, both solid state and tube designs.

Because of the [RIAA curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization) you can not plug a turntable into a CD or AUX rca input as the single is much to weak.

The speakers you have listed have there own power amp built in so you do not need an stereo receiver, amp or integrated amp to power them. If you had passive speakers you would need some form of amp for them.

This will be a good beginner set for you and as your knowledge and preferences change you can up grade.

I would suggest you join a forum to chat with others and learn.

[vinylengine](https://www.vinylengine.com/)  It is a great resource, You will learn how to set up, maintain and upgrade your turntable,

[Audiokarma](https://audiokarma.org/forums/index.php)  All things audio.

[stereophile](https://www.stereophile.com/forum) More All things audio.

Comment: thanks for the link !

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Why is my question off topic? I looked at all the available stack before coming on this one to ask for advice. I do not feel like I have this question in the wrong place since it is the only place that talks about this kind of material (I may be wrong, there are more than 100 stack I have may be missed one).

Comment: https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic